# How to show hierarchical clusters in google maps or other tool?

Tags: google-maps, clustering

Google maps marker can be clustered but those clusters expand on different levels.

I want to stay on a specific zoom level and cluster a set of markers. Then I want to show sub clusters inside that cluster. I can not find any way to do that in Google Maps. Is there any other tool which I can use to do that?

I want to do something like these images
[image]
[image]